# JNI error has occurred when running java with OpenCV from terminal

Tags: java, opencv, terminal

I'm trying to compile a java-program written with OpenCV 3.2.0 from the terminal. It was originally written in Eclipse with OpenCV as a user library. 
I compile it with this command:

```
javac -cp /opencv-3.2.0-java/build/bin/ *.java
```

It works with no error, the -cp command shows the path to the OpenCV jar. I then try to run everything with this command:

```
java -Djava.library.path="/opencv-3.2.0-java/build/lib" -cp jar/opencv-320.jar -classpath . Main
```

It gives me this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Mat
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opencv.core.Mat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I searched for solutions to this problem and came to the conclusion that it had something to do with native libraries. I use the `-Djava` parameter to link to the path of the library files from OpenCV, but it still doesn't work somehow. How do I fix this?

**EDIT:**

All the .java files are on a folder on the desktop. This is were the Main file is included. For example:

```
home/pi/Desktop/MultiSensor_v2.0_Java/Main.java
```

The path to the OpenCV jar:

```
/home/pi/Desktop/MultiSensor_v2.0_Java/opencv-3.2.0-java/build/bin/opencv-320.jar
```

The path to OpenCV native libraries:

```
/home/pi/Desktop/MultiSensor_v2.0_Java/opencv-3.2.0-java/build/lib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-cp` is short for `-classpath`. So I suspect that when you use both, the second one overwrites the first.

You can have multiple entries on the class path separated by `:` as stated in the documentation: [Setting the class path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). (actually, it looks like that is a typo in the doc, and it should be `;` as a separator. You could try both)

If you execute your command from the directory `home/pi/Desktop/MultiSensor_v2.0_Java/` that would make:

```
java -Djava.library.path="opencv-3.2.0-java/build/lib" -cp .:opencv-3.2.0-java/build/bin/opencv-320.jarr Main
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still get the same error however. What else could be the issue?

Comment: @FelixEder Note that the classpath should be set to the default package. I could help you if you edit your question to include the folder structure of the files you're using.

Comment: I just edited my question with the folder structure.

Comment: @FelixEder I updated the command. Where did you get `jar/opencv-320.jar` from? that's not a path to the jar.

Comment: I changed the path after posting my original question, sorry about that. Will update the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @FelixEder I noticed some conflicting things in the documentation. Some parts say to use `:` as a separator and some parts say you use `;`. I tested it myself, and for me it work only if I use `;` as a separator. You could try that too. (tbh, I remembered it was `;` at first, but I checked the doc and it said `:`. *sigh*)

Comment: I ran your command and it worked! Thanks so much, very irritating issue!

Comment: @FelixEder Great :) You could use an IDE instead, I use Eclipse myself, it allows me to just plug in the path to the jar and native library, which saves a lot of typing later.